# Yii2 GridView how to display column only when some filter is active

Tags: gridview, filter, yii2, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a Yii2 GridView with implemented sortable option (I used [kotchuprik extension](https://github.com/kotchuprik/yii2-sortable-widgets)) which add one column with drag'n'drop ability. The problem is that I need to be able to sort rows when some filter id GridView is set. GridView have column "Machine ID" and sorting need to be done only with rows with the same "Machine ID", so how to display column with drag'n'drop ability only when some Machine ID is set by column filter??

Answer (score 0):

You could use the visible property of the column

Yii\grid\DataColumn  has visible property. 
This attrribute  accepts boolean values, 
but  you can dynamically using  an expression that boolean value. eg:

```
  use Yii;

  ...

          'columns' => [
              ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
              //'tipo',
              ['attribute' => 'your_attribute',    
                  'label' => 'Your Label', 
                  'visible' => isThisColumnVisible(),

              ],
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$visible-detail

You can check $searchModel->your_attribute  or a equivalent functin that return boolean

```
          'columns' => [
              ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
              //'tipo',
              ['attribute' => 'your_attribute',    
                  'label' => 'Your Label', 
                  'visible' => isset($searchModel->your_attribute) ,

              ],
```

Comment: Thank you but how to check if filter is active (something was selected from dropdown filter)?

Comment: what do you mean for "if the filter is active" ?

Comment: Active mean something was selected from the dropdown-type filter (and data was refreshed including that filter)